# Exim retrieving attachments or forwarding email in queue

Tags: email, exim

My mail server has gone down due to an attack and I am moving it to a secure cloud server.

Is there a way to redirect any incoming mail for a user to a different address, such as mike@mike.co.uk will be redirected to mike@mike2.co.uk ?

If this is not possible because I have mail just sitting in the exim queue and I need to get the attachments from them; is there a way to retrieve those attachments from the command line ?

Comment: Why are you changing the domain? You could have just updated the MX records to point to your new server and left the domain alone.

Comment: If you have email sitting in your local `exim` mail queue then it's unlikely it's pending local delivery. It's more likely to be waiting to leave your system for an off-site destination. (Or you've got a badly configured system.)

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias in `/etc/aliases` for `mike@mike.co.uk` that points to `mike@mike2.co.uk` and rerun the queue with `exim -qff`.

(Although I'm still puzzled why you would have inbound email sitting in a local queue.)